# Making out of sample predictions using statsmodels SARIMAX with exogenous variable

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima, sarimax

I would like to make out of sample predictions on the validation set on a fitted SARIMAX model from statsmodels in the following way:

1. Make predictions on the first 40ish steps of the validation set given the relevant `exog` and `endog` inputs without updating the parameters
2. Refit the parameters with only the first 24ish steps of the previous 40ish steps
3. Repeat step 1 with the next 40 steps after the 24 steps from step 2, so there will be some overlap in the predictions in consecutive iterations

What's the API-centric way of doing this? From the cross validation section on [Forecasting in statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_forecasting.html), what I want to do is similar to what's supported by `append` and `extend`, but both seem to update the data on every call which is not desirable for step 1.